# Git nested repos

Tags: git, github

I have 2 repos, A and B and I want to nest B inside A (add it as a sub folder). I just placed B inside A, but the problem is that when I do any modification on repo B, it's not added or even considered in Reop A.

What change or modification should I do to make it considered as repo A?

Considering that repo A is private and repo B is public on GitHub, would that make any difference also?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should implement B as a [submodule](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial).

```
git submodule add git://yourdomain.com/path/to/B path/to/B
```

Where `git://yourdomain.com/path/to/B` is the distant path to B.
And `path/to/B` is the local directory where you want to put it in A.

Then every time you'll clone the repo A, you will have to do a `git submodule update`. And B will be up to date.

Capistrano manages it automatically if you define the `:git_enable_submodules` to true.